# How to create a histogram with 2 legends based on dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query, pivot-chart

I have a table that is created automatically from Power Query.

It looks like this:

```
| Event              | Start Date | End Date   |
+--------------------+------------+------------+
| Champion's League  | 2019-06-01 | 2019-06-03 |
| NBA Cup            | 2019-06-02 | 2019-06-03 |
| McDonald's Contest | 2019-06-03 | 2019-06-05 |
| Hot Dog Contest    | 2019-06-02 | 2019-06-06 |
...
```

It has about 20'000 rows of data.
I would like to have an histogram (I mean bar chart from PivotChart) showing for each day the number of events starting and ending. Note that this table has been created using Power Query and is dynamically recreated so, as far as I know, I can't just add Excel function as helpers.

Here's the output I would like:
(Left column: #of event starting
Right column: #of event ending)

```
.. |
.. |
.. |
.. |
.5 |
.4 |
.3 |         2     2
.2 |    1    +    1+         1    1
.1 |    +0   |0   +|   00   0+   0+
.0 |____|+___|+___||___++___+|___+|_
        01   02   03   04   05   06
        06   06   06   06   06   06
      2019 2019 2019 2019 2019 2019
```

How can I achieve that efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

In the Power Query, I would select the 2 date columns and choose **Unpivot Columns** (from the **Transform** ribbon.

That will produce 2 rows for each input row in a "Tidy Data" layout - a column for the type of observation (Start or End Date) and another for the observation date.

More on Tidy Data:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data

The first reference link goes into more detail:

https://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v059i10/v59i10.pdf